# How to convert int to char[] in c++

Tags: c++, char, int

How could i go about converting 56 and 124 to a character array? I don't understand how you could split up an integer and put it into different parts of a character array.
I want to put

```
int num = 56;
```

into

```
char num[3]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to take an integer (56) and convert it to char[2] containing '5' and '6'? Please give more details.

Comment: yes that is what im trying to do.

Comment: what about `sprintf (buff, "%d", num);`?

Comment: that's way more c then c++

Comment: @john `char num[3]` is also way more C than C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want a pure C++ solution, here it is:

C++11:

```
std::string numStr = std::to_string(num);
```

C++98:

```
std::ostringstream strm;
strm << num;
std::string numStr = strm.str();
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to rewrite itoa here is a well explain implementation of it :

```
char* itoa(int num, char* str, int base)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool isNegative = false;

    /* Handle 0 explicitely, otherwise empty string is printed for 0 */
    if (num == 0)
    {
        str[i++] = '0';
        str[i] = '\0';
        return str;
    }

    // In standard itoa(), negative numbers are handled only with
    // base 10. Otherwise numbers are considered unsigned.
    if (num < 0 && base == 10)
    {
        isNegative = true;
        num = -num;
    }

    // Process individual digits
    while (num != 0)
    {
        int rem = num % base;
        str[i++] = (rem > 9)? (rem-10) + 'a' : rem + '0';
        num = num/base;
    }

    // If number is negative, append '-'
    if (isNegative)
        str[i++] = '-';

    str[i] = '\0'; // Append string terminator

    // Reverse the string
    reverse(str, i);

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), if you want to convert the integer into a null-terminated string which would represent it.

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

Comment: That's if OP meant to convert the integer into a null-terminated string which would represent it. Possibly, the task is to copy the bytes of the integer into a `char` array. In addition, since the question is tagged as C++, you might as well use `std::to_string(value)`.

Comment: itoa is bad because it might not work on all systems

Comment: @john give me one system where it won't work on

Comment: from reading online its not guaranteed to work

Comment: That sort of statement is useless without context. If `itoa` didn't work, it wouldn't be in the language standard library.

Comment: itoa() is a perfectly acceptable alternative.

Comment: ok without using atoi. i want to try to create a function that does the same thing

Comment: If you want to reimplement itoa, look for the source code online http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa